# Gradle do not use the updated file from an extracted archive

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have a multi-module project that goes as follow `server-core -> server-game`
The server-core module bundle an `app.properties` file which I would like to override certain values when I build the server-game's executable jar.

To do so, I added an `eachFile` closure on the jar task to update the file content while building the jar but it turns out when editing the file using the ant.propertyfile task, it won't appear edited in the resulting jar:

[image: jar task]
[image: task result]

I tried with another property file named `app2.properties` which is located inside the server-game resource folder and this one get updated in the final jar. More confusing when I check the `app.properties` file in the gradle tmp folder used to build the final jar it is properly edited.

Also if I filter the files content it will be reflected properly on the final jar for both files.

It seems that files extracted from another archive are simply ignored. If it is the case I wonder why do gradle bothers extracting them in the first place ?

Any idea of what could be wrong here ?

Edit: I created a small github project that reproduce the issue. It is available [here](https://github.com/jhoukem/gradle-process-resources-test).

Run the `fatJar` task and you will see in its output that only the `app2.properties` is updated in the resulting jar even though the `app.properties` has been updated in the tmp folder it has been extracted to during the build process.

Comment: Can you post an actual full example that shows what you are seeing? It's hard to try and reproduce a screenshot of a bit of some code

Comment: @tim_yates I added a small project that can reproduce the issue running a single task could you give it a try please ?